# Using values specified in renderUI and selectInput in RShiny

Tags: r, dynamic, shiny

I've been messing around with a [Boston 311 Request Dataset](https://data.cityofboston.gov/City-Services/311-Service-Requests/awu8-dc52), specifically for learning RShiny. Ultimately the goal is to show time series plots of the time it takes to close 311 requests by neighborhood, and by the type of city department.

The idea is fairly straight forward, the user sees two `selectInput` commands, one drop-down that defines the neighborhood in Boston, then the second drop-down that specifies the relevant department for requests within that neighborhood.

Not all neighborhoods have the same type of requests, so I use `renderUI` to render the second `selectInput` dynamically.

The problem I'm having right now getting data returned to me using `renderUI` in my server function.

Here is my code for the server function (an edited snippet of the whole function)

```
server <- function(input, output) {

    data <- city_data

    neighborhood_dat <- reactive({
        data <- selectNeighborhood(data, input$neighborhood)

    })

    # Uses neighborhood dat to generate the relevant list of subjects / city departments dynamically
    subject_data <- reactive({
        data <- neighborhood_dat()
        data <- list(unique(data$SUBJECT))
        data <- data[[1]]
    })

    # Renders the select input function dynamically, choices are based on the variable subject_data()
    output$select_subject <- renderUI({
        data <- subject_data()
        selectInput("select_subject", 
                    "Department: ",
                    choices = data)
    })

    # Uses ggplot to plot the data.
    # The selectDept() function takes a dataframe, and selects out the relevant department.
    # The idea is that the input$select_subject argument *should* be taken from  the rendered selectInput.
    ts_data <- reactive({

        data <- selectDept(data, input$select_subject)
        data$open_dt <- as.POSIXlt(data$open_dt)
        mean <- neighborhood_plot(data, input$neighborhood, mean)
        se <- neighborhood_plot(data, input$neighborhood, function(x) sqrt(var(x)/length(x)))
        means <- fortify.zoo(means)
        se <- fortify.zoo(sd)
        means$se <- se$se
        means <- means[1:(nrow(means)-1),]
    })

    output$ts_plot <- renderPlot({
        plot_dat <- ts_data()
        plot <- # Plot Args go here #
        plot
    })


}
```

Specifically, I want to focus in on the following lines of code:

```
output$select_subject <- renderUI({
        data <- subject_data()
        selectInput("select_subject", 
                    "Department: ",
                    choices = data)
    })

ts_data <- reactive({

        data <- selectDept(data, input$select_subject)
```

The `output$select_subject` is where I render a dynamic UI. `ts_data` will be used to plot the time_series data using ggplot. `data <- selectDept(data, input$select_subject)` specifies a function that takes two arguments: a dataframe, and a department/subject name (specified by `input$select_subject`). The `input$select_subject` bit doesn't work, and I'm a bit stumped about how to get the department / subject name from my `renderUI` object.

Here is my ui code for completeness:

```
ui <- fluidPage(

    titlePanel("Boston 311 Request Times"),

    sidebarLayout(

        sidebarPanel(
            selectInput("neighborhood", 
                        "Neighborhood: ",
                        choices = neighborhood_list),
            htmlOutput("select_subject")

        ),


        tabPanel("Plot",
                 fluidRow(
                     column(12, plotOutput("ts_plot"))

            )

        )

    )

)
```

Comment: use `uiOutput` instead of `htmlOutput`

Comment: uiOutput is currently just an alias for htmlOutput.  -- `?uiOutput`. You can even try just run `htmlOutput("select_subject")` vs `uiOutput("select_subject")` in console and see what you get. No magic here.

Answer (score 0):

First you should make your code reproducible, so people can run it and verify their answers. You only need to generate some simulated data to replace the real data in your code.

Since I cannot test it and I don't have time to create test data by myself, I'd guess the problem came from you used same id for the ui item and select input, that confused Shiny. The dynamic UI item need one id, and the actual select input need another unique id. Then you use the id for the select input.

For the dynamic UI, it's just a placeholder in html. You can run `htmlOutput("select_subject")` in console and see what you will get. Surprisingly simple, right? Then the actual select input will be inserted there dynamically. Now you have two items so you need two unique id.